# Can I move "Pages" of apps in iOS 5?

Tags: ipad, ios

I have an iOS 5 iPad 2 and my homescreen is a bit confused. My apps are stored in pages of like content but the pages aren't logically ordered. Is there a way I can move a whole page of apps/reorder them (not just one app at a time)?

Comment: iOS 11 users: you should be looking at this answer instead: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/is-there-a-way-to-rearrange-home-screens-on-ios

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can move it by pages in the iTunes interface but (so far as I know) not on the iPad itself.

- Connect to your computer
- open iTunes
- select the iPad in the left column
- select the apps tab along the top

At this point at the upper right is a view of the apps on the iPad.  You can drag and drop apps to move them around.  You can grab a page and drag it up and down the list to rearrange the pages.

Comment: I assume I have to be plugged in via USB to do this? I'll have to try this at home.

Comment: Just tested it. As long as the device is connected to iTunes and visible in the sidebar it works, even over wifi.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can.

Just simply hold the icon first with your finger so that they all start to jiggle.

After that, simply take one of the app icons under your finger and move it towards either end in your screen.  Just keep it going for either direction for about 2 seconds.

After that it will move to another page.

Hope the answer helped :)

EDIT and now I noticed I didn't read the original question with enough accuracy.

Comment: You should delete incorrect answers. Don't just edit them to indicate their incorrect'ness.