# Is there a way to rearrange home screens on iOS?

Tags: applications, icon, ios

I used to be able to arrange the home screens ( pages ) in iTunes prior to iOS 11. I could create new empty pages, ect.

Is there a way to do this? For instance switch homescreen #2 for homescreen #3?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on your setup, you have two options.

- **OPTION 1 - Use iTunes 12.6.3 instead**. Refer to this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/303660/168832) for more details!
- **OPTION 2 - Use Apple Configurator 2**. Download and install Apple Configurator.

[Apple Configurator 2](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12) provides much more advanced features in terms of managing your iOS devices. However, if you don't already have it installed, then the current version (v2.5) requires macOS Sierra 10.12.5 or later to run.

Once installed:

1. Connect your iPhone via USB to your Mac
2. Launch Apple Configurator 2
3. Select your iPhone
4. Go to Actions > Modify > Home Screen Layout...
5. Your screens will appear
6. Click and hold the mouse pointer on the screen outline and drag it to change its order. So, using your example, click and hold the outline for screen 3 and drag it to the left of screen 2.
7. Click on the blue <kbd>Apply</kbd> button at bottom right.

Comment: It’s a solid answer, and I’m glad that I found it. There are two caveats: The UI for managing homescreens is... A bit amateurish. Also, this doesn’t work for iOS 13, unfortunately - it appears to be mostly incompatible. Apple’s software competence appears to be becoming more of a nostalgic memory than a reality, unfortunately.

Comment: As mentioned in @ColinS's answer and according to my testing, you can't rearrange icons with Apple Configurator 2 when running iOS 13 (iOS 12 works). The app doesn't seem to be getting much love from Apple, dark mode isn't supported either.

Comment: Update: Configurator 2 version 2.13.1 (5A35), released today, adds support for rearraging icons in iOS 13 and even dark mode.

Comment: In iOS 14+, rearranging home screens using Apple Configurator 2 will remove all widgets  placed on screens though. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Configurator 2 not longer works. Certainly with iOS 13, it will let you change the order of apps and screens, but when you click Apply nothing changes on the device. AFAIK, Apple has been aware of this since September 2019 but have not fixed it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your post, I can confirm that Apple Configurator 2 doesn't work with iOS 13 (although iOS 12 works).

Comment: Configurator 2 version 2.13.1 (5A35), released today, finally adds support for rearraging icons in iOS 13.